Как можно ограничить dll так, чтобы в ней не мог выполниться вредоносный код?
Есть идея сделать моды для игры с помощью dll, но не хочется подвергать обычных пользователей опасности что сторонний мод может содержать троян или еще что-то. Можно ли как-то запретить вызов windows api в dll? Точнее скорее разрешить только конкретные функции
Еще один вопрос, а может ли это полностью спасти от вредоносного кода?

Код из dll может делать что угодно в памяти вашего приложения. Это значит что он вообще может делать что угодно.

В качестве альтернативы попробуйте реализовать луа скриптинг. Тогда вы самостоятельно сможете задавать функции, доступные для скриптов мода. С нативными библиотеками такое сделать затруднительно.

@user7860670 в игре уже реализованы моды через луа, но он ограничен своим функционалом. Как вариант еще обязывать людей выкладывать на гитхабе моды, а после компилировать их при загрузке из репозитория
